# Get ID of View in GridView

Tags: android, gridview, android-cursor, onitemclicklistener

**What I've tried**

---

Hello Guys, I first created a database which I've filled with 3 Collumns, *RowID, imageID, text.* Afterwards I created a GridView which if filled over my database. Now I have created a onItemClickListner, in which I'd like to get the imageID over the position.
After that happend I serach my DB-Table after this imageID, to get the *text*. This stuff I nneed to save in my other Table.
The problem is I think, that I don't get the imageID, and like this serach for nothin in the DB, if you take a look at the Logcat you see that it's null, so it probably didn't get the imageID or I search in my DBAdapter not like I should.

**Question**

---

**IMPORTRANT:**
I finally get the ID of the View thx to FuzzialLogic, but there is still a problem, I can't get Row over my Cursor. Please take a look at that!

---

**WORKS**:

What do I need to change in my Code, that I can get the ID of the Image the User clicked on. Afterwards I'd like to search my DB with that Image-ID, to get the Text which I stored with the Image.
This stuff afterwards goes in my other Table.

Down here you see the Code and LogCat-Log.
I also added my DatabaseAdapter if someone needs it.
Thx for your help in Advance!

**Code**

---

**SFilterConfigActivity.class:**

```
    package de.retowaelchli.filterit;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.*;

import de.retowaelchli.filterit.database.SmileyDBAdapter;
import de.retowaelchli.filterit.database.SFilterDBAdapter;
import de.retowaelchli.filterit.stats.ImageAdapter;




public class SFilterConfigActivity extends Activity {
    
    //Variablen deklarieren
    private String name;
    private String keyword;
    private String smiley;
    private String text;
    
    private String source;
    private Integer[] info;
    
    private SmileyDBAdapter SmileyHelper;
    private SFilterDBAdapter mDbHelper;
    
    
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sfilter_config);
    
      SmileyHelper = new SmileyDBAdapter(this);
      mDbHelper = new SFilterDBAdapter(this);
      
      getImages();
      grid();
    }


public void grid(){
    
    //Hier wird die GridView definiert und anschliesend über den ImageAdapter gefüllt
    final GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.SmileyGrind);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, info));

    
    //Hier wird definiert was passiert wenn auf ein Bild in der GridView geklickt wird
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(SFilterConfigActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           // gridview.setSelection(position);
           // Funktioniert noch nich Custom GridView Layout dafür erstellen siehe Stackoverflow
            if(position == gridview.getSelectedItemPosition()){
                v.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
                
            }
            else{
                v.setBackgroundColor(0x0000000);
            }
            
            //Hier wird herrausgefunden welche ID das Bild hat und in den jeweiligen String gespeichert
            source = (new Long(id)).toString();
            
            SmileyHelper.open();
            Cursor c = SmileyHelper.getSmiley(source);
            startManagingCursor(c);

            if (c.moveToFirst()) { 
                do { 
                text = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SmileyDBAdapter.SOURCE)); 
                smiley = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SmileyDBAdapter.INFO)); 
                
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            SmileyHelper.close();
            

            }

        }
        
    });
}


public Integer[] getImages(){
    
    SmileyHelper.open();
    
    Cursor c = SmileyHelper.getAllSmileys();
    
    ArrayList<Integer> infoList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    
    c.getColumnIndex(SmileyDBAdapter.INFO);
    int ColumnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(SmileyDBAdapter.INFO);
    
    if(c!=null)
    {
       
       while(c.moveToNext()){
           String infoItem = c.getString( ColumnIndex );
           infoList.add(Integer.parseInt(infoItem));
       }
    }


    info = infoList.toArray(new Integer[]{});

    c.close();
    
    
    SmileyHelper.close();
  
    
    return info;
    
}



public void onClickSConfigSave(View v){
    
    EditText edtTextName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.SFConfigName);
    EditText edtTextKeyword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.SFConfigKeyword);
    
    name = edtTextName.getText().toString();
    keyword = edtTextKeyword.getText().toString();
    
    mDbHelper.open();
    mDbHelper.createSFilter(name, keyword, smiley, text);
    mDbHelper.close();
    
    final Intent i = new Intent(this, SmileyActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

**ImageAdapter.class**

```
    package de.retowaelchli.filterit.stats;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;


//import de.retowaelchli.filterit.SFilterConfigActivity;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    
    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds;
    private Context mContext;
    
    
    public ImageAdapter(Context c, Integer[] imageIds) {
        mContext = c;
        mThumbIds = imageIds;
        
    }
    
    

    public int getCount() {
       return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        
        imageView.setId(mThumbIds[position]);
        
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
       
        
        
        
        return imageView;
        
        
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Like this I added the pictures with some text to the DB:

```
   private void angry(){
        
        int drawableID = context.getResources().getIdentifier("angry", "drawable", getPackageName());
        iv.setImageResource(drawableID);
        
        //String info = String.valueOf(drawableID);
        String info = String.valueOf(drawableID);
        
        mDbHelper.open();
        
        mDbHelper.createSmiley("You received a angry message", info);
        
        mDbHelper.close();
    }
```

**Log-Cat**

---

And here's the Log:

```
10-12 11:32:29.632: DEBUG/Database(25130): dbopen(): path = /data/data/de.retowaelchli.filterit/databases/filterit, flag = 6
10-12 11:32:29.632: DEBUG/Database(25130): dbopen(): path = /data/data/de.retowaelchli.filterit/databases/filterit, free size = 663
10-12 11:32:30.612: DEBUG/Database(25130): dbopen(): path = /data/data/de.retowaelchli.filterit/databases/filterit, flag = 6
10-12 11:32:30.612: DEBUG/Database(25130): dbopen(): path = /data/data/de.retowaelchli.filterit/databases/filterit, free size = 663
10-12 11:32:30.632: ERROR/Database(25130): Error inserting text=null smiley=null keyword=test name=test
10-12 11:32:30.632: ERROR/Database(25130): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
10-12 11:32:30.632: ERROR/Database(25130):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
10-12 11:32:30.632: ERROR/Database(25130):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:61)
10-12 11:32:30.632: ERROR/Database(25130):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1671)
10-12 11:32:30.632: ERROR/Database(25130):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1515)
10-12 11:32:30.632: ERROR/Database(25130):     at de.retowaelchli.filterit.database.SFilterDBAdapter.createSFilter(SFilterDBAdapter.java:89)
10-12 11:32:30.632: ERROR/Database(25130):     at de.retowaelchli.filterit.SFilterConfigActivity.onClickSConfigSave(SFilterConfigActivity.java:143)
10-12 11:32:30.632: ERROR/Database(25130):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-12 11:32:30.632: ERROR/Database(25130):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-12 11:32:30.632: ERROR/Database(25130):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2186)
10-12 11:32:30.632: ERROR/Database(25130):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
10-12 11:32:30.632: ERROR/Database(25130):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9277)
10-12 11:32:30.632: ERROR/Database(25130):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-12 11:32:30.632: ERROR/Database(25130):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-12 11:32:30.632: ERROR/Database(25130):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
10-12 11:32:30.632: ERROR/Database(25130):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
10-12 11:32:30.632: ERROR/Database(25130):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-12 11:32:30.632: ERROR/Database(25130):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-12 11:32:30.632: ERROR/Database(25130):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-12 11:32:30.632: ERROR/Database(25130):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-12 11:32:30.632: ERROR/Database(25130):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

Here you find the Code of my SmileyDBAdapter.

**SmileyDB**

```
package de.retowaelchli.filterit.database;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class SmileyDBAdapter {
    
        public static final String ROW_ID = "_id";
        public static final String SOURCE = "source";
        public static final String INFO = "info";

        private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "smiley";

        private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
        private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

        private final Context mCtx;

        private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

            DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
                super(context, DBAdapter.DATABASE_NAME, null, DBAdapter.DATABASE_VERSION);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            }
        }

        /**
         * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
         * opened/created
         * 
         * @param ctx
         *            the Context within which to work
         */
        public SmileyDBAdapter(Context ctx) {
            this.mCtx = ctx;
        }


        public SmileyDBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
            this.mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.mCtx);
            this.mDb = this.mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * close return type: void
         */
        public void close() {
            this.mDbHelper.close();
        }


        public long createSmiley(String source, String info ){
            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put(SOURCE, source);
            initialValues.put(INFO, info);
            return this.mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
        }


        public boolean deleteSmiley(long rowId) {

            return this.mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, ROW_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
        }

        public Cursor getAllSmileys() {

            return this.mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { ROW_ID,
                    SOURCE, INFO }, null, null, null, null, null);
        }
        


        
        //Es wird nach der ID des smiley gesucht.
        public Cursor getSmiley(String info) throws SQLException {

            Cursor mCursor =

            this.mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { ROW_ID, SOURCE,
                    INFO }, INFO + "=" + info, null, null, null, null, null);
            if (mCursor != null) {
                mCursor.moveToFirst();
            }
            return mCursor;
        }


        public boolean updateSmiley(long rowId, String source, String info,
                String cache){
            ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
            args.put(SOURCE, source);
            args.put(INFO, info);

            return this.mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, ROW_ID + "=" + rowId, null) >0; 
        }

    }
```

**DBAdapter**

```
package de.retowaelchli.filterit.database;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBAdapter {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "filterit";

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_ADFILTER = "create table adfilter (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + ADFilterDBAdapter.NAME+" not null ,"
    + ADFilterDBAdapter.KEYWORD+" not null ,"
    + ADFilterDBAdapter.CACHE + " not null );";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SFILTER = "create table sfilter (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    +SFilterDBAdapter.NAME+" not null ,"
    +SFilterDBAdapter.KEYWORD+" not null ,"
    +SFilterDBAdapter.SMILEY+ " not null ,"
    +SFilterDBAdapter.TEXT+ " not null );";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ADMESSAGES = "create table admessages (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    +MessagesDBAdapter.PHONENUMBER+" not null ,"
    +MessagesDBAdapter.MESSAGE+ " not null );";

    
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SMILEY = " create table smiley (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    +SmileyDBAdapter.SOURCE+" not null ,"
    +SmileyDBAdapter.INFO+ " not null );";
    
    
    private final Context context; 
    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param ctx
     */
    public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
        {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ADFILTER);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SFILTER);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ADMESSAGES);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SMILEY);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
        int newVersion) 
        {               
            // Adding any table mods to this guy here
        }
    } 

   /**
     * open the db
     * @return this
     * @throws SQLException
     * return type: DBAdapter
     */
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        this.DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.context);
        this.db = this.DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * close the db 
     * return type: void
     */
    public void close() 
    {
        this.DBHelper.close();
    }

}
```

---

Comment: Hey Fuzzical Logic, I'd like to get the ID of the View(picture) over the position. If you take a deeper look into my DBAdapter, i serach the table after the imageID.

Comment: OK. I see what you are trying to do here. I ran into some similar problems with a couple of different adapter types. I found an effective solution, but it took some fumbling around. Let me see if I can find the solution. (P.S. I always ask for clarification, even if I have read the code, because just because the code SAYS something, doesn't mean that is what the person is trying to accomplish. Thanks for the clarification!)

Comment: no problem! That's great that you have something like this, allready thx for you solution/help in advance!

Comment: it don't has to be fast, it just has to work ;)

Comment: Okay, after reviewing your edit, your Table doesn't declare a type for SOURCE. This means that it get inserted and read as whatever it goes in as. Furthermore, your Log says that the inserts are violating the constraints. This would indicate that there is not actually any data in that table. Are you sure that there is data in that table? (i.e. have you tried a query for all rows?)

Comment: Yes, if there wouldn't be anything in it, it wouldn't show pictures because i filled my gridview over that database =).

Comment: Gotcha. then, review my edited answer in a second.

Comment: Safari, was your issue solved then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari,

After looking over your code and analyzing what could be causing the error, I've noticed a few things. The issue is that your code is trying to interchange the rowID and viewID, but that is not actually the desired behavior.

In `OnItemClick()`, the `id` argument refers to `rowID`. You don't actually have a `rowID` that is guaranteed (by the code) to be unique, so it is failing. While you could "force the issue" via `getItemId()`, that function merely provides a pointer to an object (Integer). Ignore `getItemId()` as this is only causing you pain. Instead, grab the view itself, and get the `viewId` directly from it, like so:

***EDIT***   `source = v.getId().toString();`
*Reason:* Since your TABLE doesn't declare a Type, it is most likely going in as a String. We know the ImageID is now returning, and we know the data is there... So that leaves type conversion, so far as I can tell.

`parent` and `view` often cause confusion, particularly with convoluted nested layouts like `GridViews` and `ListViews`. However, your `GridView` is quite simple and `v` should refer to the `ImageView` that is stored there. If the `ImageView` was stored in a `LinearLayout` or other similar parent, there might be an issue, but such is not the case for you.

This will bypass your need to worry about the `getItemId(int position)`, as again, this refers to `rowId` and only works if you can guarantee to the `Adapter` certain things, specifically a unique `rowId` for each item.

Second, your `viewId` is set to a pointer for an `Integer` and not the value itself. An `int` is a primitive, so assignment happens as expected. An `Integer` is an `Object` so assignment happens to the address of the object, not the object itself. I would suggest changing `imageView.setId(mThumbIds[position]);` (in your `getView()`) to:

```
   imageView.setId(mThumbIds[position].intValue());
```

This will get the primitive `int` value instead of a reference to an `Integer` object in memory. Unless something else errant is happening in your code (and I don't see anything right offhand), this should resolve your issue. `setId` is meant to fail quietly if an inappropriate `id` is assigned to it, so it may not be working and simply not telling you.

Finally, I can't see what type of field the 'SOURCE' is in your code. It doesn't show the actual table creation. So, further guessing at your particular database is impossible. Hope this helps!

***Regarding your Database***
The main thing that stands out about your Database is your CREATE TABLE statement for your Simleys Table. In SQLite, if you do not explicitly assign a Type, SQLite will determine the Type each time you make a query, and return the type according to what it believes is in the field. This means that numbers may be interpreted as String and vice versa. In general, it can be pretty reliable, however, it can lead to pitfalls.

One of the biggest issues in code is assuming the code is doing what you want it to. In fact, you can only guarantee this if you tell it exactly what to do.

Second, I noticed that when you get the images to build your `Array` for your `ImageAdapter` that you are doing a query on the `INFO` field, not the `SOURCE`. This is misleading in your code as you tell the `onItemClick` that you are getting the `SOURCE`. Consider changing this variable name.

Next, there is a dysfunction when querying the `INFO` field via `getSmiley(String info)`. It is expecting a String and not an Integer according to your arguments. Adding a `String` to a `ContentValues` object is different than adding an Integer. A `String` gets added with '' surrounding it, separating '1' from 1. This means that all of your `Integers` were INSERTED as `String` and when you are querying you are not including the necessary ''. So a number of changes is advised.

- First, adjust your CREATE TABLE Statement.

  private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SMILEY = " create table smiley (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
  +SmileyDBAdapter.SOURCE+" not null ,"
  +SmileyDBAdapter.INFO+ " integer not null );";

Changing the statement in this way will ensure that you are getting an integer and not a string.

- Next, change your `getImages()` in the following manner: `String infoItem = c.getString( ColumnIndex );` to `int infoItem = c.getInt( ColumnIndex );`
- Next, change your `createSmiley(String source, String info)` to `createSmiley(String source, int info)` . This should adjust all of your inserts correctly. Your `ContentValues` object (named `initialValues`) will know what to do.
- Next, change your `getSmiley(String info)` to `getSmiley(int info)`. This should adjust your query correctly as well. If it does not, change `... + "=" + info + ...` to `... + "=" + info.toString() + ...`. This will force the issue for you.
- Next, make your `onItemClick()` match by changing this line `source = v.getId().toString();` back to `source = v.getId();`
- Finally, you will have to change any of your calls to `createSmiley()` to send the int value, not the value converted to a String.

This is a lot of changes (not really) to make. So, please back up your source files before you make these changes. Then its just a matter of uninstalling the package (including from the emulator, if it is emulated) and reinstalling it, so it doesn't keep the original data (with the Strings and not the Integers).

FuzzicalLogic

Comment: thats to great like this I get the ImageID but it seems, when I search the DB I don't get the needed values... I'll have to check this again. Thx again, if you see a problem in the SmileyDBAdapter for searching an entrie please just tell me.. :D thx!

Comment: So, now you get the ImageID, but it doesn't query the database correctly? Am I understanding you? If that's the case, can you show me the 'CREATE TABLE' statement you are using to create your actual table? This would help big time.

Comment: Exactly you understood me! I'll post it tomorrow! Thx again

Comment: did you found the problem!? please say yes :)

Comment: I'll accept your anwser, but please search a way to get this little part there working, that would be absolutily awsome..!! Green Tick for you! But please find a way!

Comment: Which little part? You mean getting the data back from the Database? If that is the case, I believe the toString() may solve the issue. I would probably recreate the database with an explicit type on the SOURCE of INTEGER. This will make sure that the Type isn't guessed at by SQLite. I'll put an explanation in a new edit, but give me a couple of hours... Its a little hectic today.

Comment: I read trough your update and I tried something similar, what worked for me. So +50 and le green Tick for you!

Answer (score 2):

In Your ImageAdapter code.You have overridden method getItemid ther you are returning 0 that is causing problem.try returning mThumbIds[position] i think this will do the trick  for you.

cheers.

Comment: i changed it to this     `public long getItemId(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position] ;
    }`same error trough....

Comment: @safari I think you should use to 'public long getItemId(int position) { return position};

Comment: use source = (new Long(id)).toString(); and public long getItemId(int position) { return position}; Can it work?

Comment: owh didn't saw this post and your anwser, ill try ii - didn't work, but still thx mate, ill try your other anwser but atm I don't get where i have to input your codelines

Answer (score 1):

In ImageAdapter class in getView method add the following line of code

```
imageView.setId(mThumbIds[postion]);
```

or another option is in your Onclick listener of gridview inside on click method

```
source = (new Long(id)).toString();
```

replace this line of code with

```
source = parent.getItemId(position);
```

Now this will definately solve the issue.

Comment: Hello first i tried the thing you told me above afterwards - didn't work, afterwards I tried the secound thing you told me but I don't get this code working... :( `source = parent.getItemId(position);`

Answer (score 0):

change

```
  if(c!=null)
    {

       while(c.moveToNext()){
           String infoItem = c.getString( ColumnIndex );
           infoList.add(Integer.parseInt(infoItem));
       }
    }
```

to

```
if(c!=null)
        {

           while(!c.isAfterLast()){
               String infoItem = c.getString( ColumnIndex );
               infoList.add(Integer.parseInt(infoItem));
               c.moveToNext();
           }
        }
```

Comment: I don't get what this method `!isAfterLast` should be.

Comment: when do the exception happen?