# Custom Gridview getitemid() does not return right row_id

Tags: android, gridview, onitemclicklistener

I am using custom `GridView` inside `ScrollView`. I know it is not the right way. I do not have any other way to accomplished my app layout.

I am trying to get `item id == row_id` of database in `GridView` but it does not return right id. Instead of giving `row_id` it gives me position id of item that does not match with database `row_id`
I know position id is `row_id` in Adapter, I do not know why id is not matching with database.

Here is `GridView` I used on layout

```
 <info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MyGridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview11"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="278dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
 />
```

Here is Custom `MyGridview` code. I used this from `Github`

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridView;

/**
 * ScrollViewの中のGridViewでも高さを可変にする<br>
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481844/gridview-height-gets-cut
 */
public class MyGridView extends GridView
{

    boolean expanded = false;

    public MyGridView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                                    int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public boolean isExpanded()
    {
        return expanded;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
        if (isExpanded())
        {
            // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
            // View.MEASURED_SIZE_MASK represents the largest height possible.
            int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK,
                    MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
            params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        else
        {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded)
    {
        this.expanded = expanded;
    }
}
```

Finally here is `onlcikListener` code that does not work properly

```
 try {
            // OnClick

            best_product_gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    //get position index of item here.

                    String indexid = String.valueOf(position);
                    Log.d("Index of Selected ", indexid);

                    // calling function
                     globalVariable.product_id =  position;
                    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).product();

                }
            });

    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      Log.d("Error BestPrduct View","" + e);
    }
```

Here is Adapter class

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu.AdpaterClass;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.R;
import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.library.Function_List;
import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.library.Global_JsonTags;
import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.library.Global_Variable;

/**
 * Created by clint19 on 1/21/2016.
 */
public class Best_Product extends BaseAdapter {
    View gridView;
    private Context context;
  /*  private DisplayImageOptions options;*/

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    // josn vaules from json file library
    Global_JsonTags jsontags = new Global_JsonTags();
    Function_List lib_function =  new Function_List();
    Global_Variable globalVariable = new Global_Variable();
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArr = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    public Best_Product(Context c,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> json_value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        context = c;
        MyArr = json_value;

    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("size of item", "" + MyArr.size());
        return MyArr.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;

    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        View view = convertView;
        TextView product_name;
        TextView product_price;
        ImageView imageView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = new View(context);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_best_collection, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            assert view != null;
            imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView26);
           // holder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView26);
            holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress);
            product_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView21);
            product_price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView23);

            String name = MyArr.get(position).get("product_name");
            int namelength = name.length();
            if(namelength >= 33)
            {
                product_name.setText(MyArr.get(position).get("product_name").substring(0, 29) + "...");
            }
            else{product_name.setText(MyArr.get(position).get("product_name"));}
            product_price.setText(MyArr.get(position).get("product_price"));
            String product_status = MyArr.get(position).get("product_status");

            if(product_status.equals("false"))
            {

                Button add_to_cart = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add_to_cart1);
                add_to_cart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                View background_height = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.bestproduct1);
            }
            else
            {
                Button add_to_cart = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add_to_cart1);
                add_to_cart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            Log.d("setting up text", "setting up text");

            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(MyArr.get(position).get("product_image"))
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_stub) // optional
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_error)         // optional
                    .into(imageView);

            //view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }


        return view;
    }


    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
    }

}
```

I am trying to get id from 2 hour but no luck. 
I followed these question [How to add gridview setOnItemClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20191914/how-to-add-gridview-setonitemclicklistener) and [Android gridview OnItemClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873934/android-gridview-onitemclicklistener) and this one [Get ID of View in GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684659/get-id-of-view-in-gridview) 
 and may more.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong.

Comment: what adapter are you using ?

Comment: Best_Product  mAdapter=  new Best_Product(getActivity(), best_prpduct_array);

Comment: @AshuKumar: You are returning wrong id from the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i m trying to get item id == row_id of database of GridView but it
>   does not right id

That's because  you didn't properly override `getItemId` in your `Adapter`. Assuming that the dataset you feeding the adapter with, is made of bean classes, what you will have to do is to override `getItemId(int position)`, which returns a `long`, and let it return the correct id. E.g.

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
   return getItem(position).getId();
}
```

the correct value is passed as last parameter, `long id`, in `onItemClick`.

If you are subclassing the `CursorAdapter`(or one its concrete implementations), and you should, since you have a cursor based solution, 
you don't need to override it. The  `CursorAdapter` already returns value of the `_id` columns of the cursor at position.

**Edit**

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
   HashMap<String, String> mapAtPostion = MyArr.get(position);
   return Long.valueOf(mapAtPostion.get("product_id"));
}
```

Comment: return getItem(position).getId(); 
can not resolve getId() @Blackbelt

Comment: upadted with Adapter

Comment: does the HashMap contains the id you want to use?

Comment: hasmap contains **product_id**  is the id of row_id of product in database

Comment: I edited my answer. I strongly recommend you to use another approach, rather than HashMap<String, String>

Comment: checking... is there any problem with hashmap ?

Comment: you are treating everything as it was a `String`, even though the id is a long. Don't you see any problem in it ?

Comment: return Long.valueOf(mapAtPostion.get("product_id")); **return null **

Comment: what does that mean? Does your HashMap has an entry with key `product_id` ?

Comment: it was my typo error , still i m not getting right row_id :(

Comment: Where aren't you getting it?

Comment: now working :) i donot know why , i will give bounty to you. u saved my life

Answer (score 1):

You are getting position of the item because that is what you are returning from your method `getItemId`. You need to return the database `row_id` from that method.

Change your method like this

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
   return Long.valueOf(MyArr.get(position).get("product_id"));
}
```

Comment: That is wrong. The signature returns a long and you are returning a String

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}
```

CustmeAdapter Example

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

String [] result;
Context context;
int [] imageId;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList, int[] prgmImages) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    result=prgmNameList;
    context=mainActivity;
    imageId=prgmImages;
     inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
             getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return result.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public class Holder
{
    TextView tv;
    ImageView img;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Holder holder=new Holder();
    View rowView;

         rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.program_list, null);
         holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

     holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
     holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

     rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+result[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    return rowView;
}
```

}